# Convert Just Main Form To WPF Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, integration, mdi, windowsformshost

I Have a Windows Form Project , which has a main form,and in this form I open other form as mdi (other form opens inside of main form)

My Boss Told me to change the main form to wpf technology(for add some animation or something  else)

Now I want to have a one main windows in wpf which has a one grid in its middle to put my winform there.

What is the best idea in this case for do this job.

Comment: You want your existing winform be a control on a WPF grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this previous link, which was posted on StackOverflow for answers and links that will help you in regards to your question[Previous StackOverFlow Postng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457764/winforms-to-wpf-how-do-we-get-there-from-here)
   this posting has previously been answered

[Hosting a WinForms in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx) This is a MSDN site that will explain stepbystep how to host a wnform inside of WPF